# How to test for statistical significance in a time series

Tags: time-series, outliers

Suppose you have a bunch of data each week (one data point each week): 88,88,88,88,89,88

How do you test whether the data point 89 is a statistically significant increase?

Comment: Does anyone have any updates on this?

Comment: If your data points were i.i.d., you could estimate the probability density of the data (using a parametric or nonparametric model) and then calculate the density of the point of interest and the cumulative density of points that are more extreme than that point (which would give you a sort of p-value). For time-dependent data points (not i.i.d.) you would need some adjustment of the above idea.

Comment: So if you assume i.i.d, you could perform a t-test to see if the mean value at that data point is greater than 88?